# grails web flow doesn't work

Tags: grails, spring-webflow, grails-webflow

```
start{
          on('next'){.... }.to "connectusers" 
     }
  connectusers { 
                   on("next").to "congrats" 
     } 
  congrats()
```

this flow doesn't work but if I run each step alone it's ok
Work:

```
start{
        on('next'){.... }.to "connectusers"
      }
 connectusers {}
```

also work...

```
 start{
        on('next'){.... }.to "congrats" 
      }
 congrats()
```

where I did wrong?

Comment: Please explain "does not work".  Errors?  Exception? Please add some more verbose description of the problems you see to the question.

Comment: not pass to the next level.
It end the action correctly but don't go to the next step.